# Pass ng-model attribute to custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

So, I have a form, where I need to use a custom directive.
What i need: pass the `user` model to the directive.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.login">
    <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">

    <span ng-custom-directive ng-model="user.testfield"></span>

</form>
```

Directive template looks like this:

```
<span><input type="checkbox" ng-model="[HERE I NEED user.testfield TO WORK WITH user]"> </span>
```

How I can pass the `user` model to directive template?

After form submit I need `user.testfield` to be avaliable in the `$scope.user` like:

```
console.log($scope.user)
{
    login: 'test',
    password: 'test',
    testfield: true|false
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can solve it in the other way [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X8brIQyAwtAf6CybcnQn)

In brief:

```
scope: {
    bindedModel: "=ngModel"
},
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="bindedModel">'
```

Comment: Does this really work? When inspecting the browser elements It seems that the ng-model is hardcoded to the word "bindedModel" not the attribute value of binded-model when using this directive

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found similar question and resolved my problem in this way:

```
angular.module("myApp")
  .directive "ngCustomDirective", () ->
      restrict: 'A',

      scope:
        field: '@',
        model: '='

      template: '<span><input type="checkbox" ng-model="model[field]"></span>'
```

And directive usage will be:

```
<span ng-custom-directive
       ng-bind-model="user"
       ng-bind-field="testfield">
</span>
```

Comment: Please post a link to that similar question.  Thanks!